# How to use beaker for multiple bottle apps

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

The documentation of Bottle show how to use beaker for session management, like the following

```
import bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}
app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)

@bottle.route('/test')
def test():
  s = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
  s['test'] = s.get('test',0) + 1
  s.save()
  return 'Test counter: %d' % s['test']

bottle.run(app=app)
```

My problem is, I have multiple bottle applications, and each of them serves a virtual host (that is powered by cherrypy).  So I can not use decorate "@bottle.route", instead, I need to use decorate like "app1.route('/test')" , "app2.route('/test')"  .

But if I warp app with Beaker middleware, like the following,

```
app1= Bottle()
app2= Bottle()
app1 = SessionMiddleware(app1, session_opts)
app2 = SessionMiddleware(app2, session_opts)
```

when python run to the following ,

```
@app1.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'OK'
```

it will report error, AttributeError: 'SessionMiddleware' object has no attribute 'route'

That's for sure, because now app1 is actually a 'SessionMiddleware' not a Bottle app.

How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the beaker source code a little, finally I found the way.

Use the decorator this way:

```
@app1.wrap_app.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'OK'
```